# Django/Docker: web container not up-to-date code

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

EDIT 22/05/2022

Docker version 20.10.14
docker-compose version 1.25.0

I delete again all containers/images and re-build using `docker-compose -f docker-compose.preprod.yml build --force-rm --no-cache` but I still observe the same issue: code in not up-to-date in web container

---

I use Django docker app and do not manage to apply code update to my web container.

I've tried to delete all containers (`docker rm -f ID` ; `docker system prune`) and images (`docker rmi -f ID` ; `docker image prune`) related to my app and re-build with `docker-compose -f docker-comose.preprod.yml build`

Then I run `docker-compose -f docker-comose.preprod.yml up` but for some reasons when I connect to my web running container (`docker exec -it web sh`) and read my updated files, I observe that update are not applied...

How should I do to make my update applied?

```
# Pull the official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

# Set a work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc g++ python3-dev musl-dev

RUN apk --update add libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev musl-dev libgcc openssl-dev curl postgresql-client
RUN apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev nano
RUN pip3 install psycopg2 psycopg2-binary

# install xgettext for i18n
RUN apk add gettext

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements/ requirements/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements/preprod.txt

# Copy the entrypoint.sh file
COPY entrypoint.preprod.sh .

# Copy the initdata sql file
COPY initdata.preprod.sql .

# Copy the project's files
COPY . .

RUN chmod +x entrypoint.preprod.sh
```

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    web:
        restart: always
        container_name: ecrf_web
        build:
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.preprod
        command: gunicorn core.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - app_volume:/usr/src/app
            - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
            - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
        expose:
            - 8000
        env_file:
            - ./.env.preprod
        entrypoint: [ "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.preprod.sh" ]
        depends_on:
            - redis
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8000/" ]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 10s
            retries: 50

    redis:
        container_name: ecrf_redis
        image: "redis:alpine"

    celery:
        container_name: ecrf_celery
        build:
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.preprod
        command: celery -A core worker -l info
        volumes:
            - app_volume:/usr/src/app
        env_file:
            - ./.env.preprod
        depends_on:
            - web
            - redis

    celery-beat:
        container_name: ecrf_celery-beat
        build:
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.preprod
        command: celery -A core beat -l info
        volumes:
            - app_volume:/usr/src/app
        env_file:
            - ./.env.preprod
        depends_on:
            - web
            - redis

    nginx:
        container_name: ecrf_nginx
        build: ./nginx
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
            - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
        ports:
            - 1370:80
        depends_on:
            - web

volumes:
    static_volume:
    media_volume:
    app_volume:
```

Comment: Can you show your Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml?

Comment: What happen if you delete the `app_volume`? Why do you share the code across container anyway? Why not just copy the code in each image that you need code? The problem with the volume is that content of the volume will overwrite your updated code since you copy your code into `/usr/src/app` and volume is map there